# Merge two SELECT queries and display data in one table?

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2012

Following query is displaying data from two tables, it is working fine but I want to merge the result and display output in single table:

```
SELECT 
    ITEM_MODEL, QUANTITY 
FROM
    ITEMS_MASTER 
WHERE 
    ITEM_MODEL = 'keyboard' 

SELECT
    AVG(RATE) AS Avg_Rate,
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT 
FROM
    ITEM_DETAILS 
WHERE
    ITEM_MODEL = 'keyboard' 
GROUP BY 
    ITEM_MODEL
```

What will be the possible way of doing this I am pretty new to SQL so please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: You need to learn about [JOINs in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took both of your queries and compiled into one. This is just one of the more ways to do it

```
select 
   m.ITEM_MODEL,
   m.QUANTITY,
   d.Avg_Rate,
   d.TOTAL_AMOUNT 
from 
   (Select ITEM_MODEL, AVG(RATE) as Avg_Rate,SUM(AMOUNT) as TOTAL_AMOUNT 
    from ITEM_DETAILS 
    where ITEM_MODEL= 'keyboard' Group by ITEM_MODEL) D 
    inner join 
    ITEMS_MASTER m on m.ITEM_MODEL = d.ITEM_MODEL
```

It will show only "keyboard" because your aggregate inline query already excludes all others. Also I moved `Item_master` into second position for better performance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select ITEM_MODEL,QUANTITY 
from ITEMS_MASTER t join(
                           Select ITEM_MODEL,AVG(RATE) as Avg_Rate,SUM(AMOUNT) as                               TOTAL_AMOUNT from ITEM_DETAILS 
where ITEM_MODEL= 'keyboard' Group by ITEM_MODEL
) s 
on s.item_model = t.item_model
where ITEM_MODEL='keyboard'
```